# How to parse a item packsize to perform mathematical calculation

Tags: javascript, excel, string, parsing

I am using JavaScript to convert order unit packsize from LB to Ounces.
For example 4/15-17 LBS needs to be converted to ounces using this formula:
(16 * 2 * ((15 + 17) / 2))
I am attempting to use the following to filter to separate these into 3 variables to perform the calculation.  This will allow me to catch other similar pack sizes and perform the same conversion

This filter is good enough to catch the item to convert but I am getting a "formula parse error" during the conversion. (16* undefined * ((undefined + $3) / 2)) using:

^\d+/\d+(.\d+)?-\d+(.\d+)?\s?LBS and using (16 * $1 * (($2 + $3) / 2)) to covert to 1,024 OZ.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

I have other filters that are working for different pack sizes and conversions for example.

^\d+/\d+(.\d+)?/\d+(.\d+)?\s?LBS Converts 6/2/1 LBS to 192 OZ using ($1 * $2 * 16)

Joe

Answer (score 0):

Actually I figured out the solution.  The reason I was having such a hard time is that I had other rules that were catching the item before getting to the rule I was working on.  After cleaning up the rules I was able to figure out that the following rule works correctly.

^(\d+)/(\d+)-(\d+)?\s?LBS

In my original post I also listed the incorrect ounces for the conversion.  4/15-17 LBS converts to 1,024 ounces.